# Keep iPhone Unlocked while Debugging with Rider

Tags: ios, maui, rider

I'm writing an app using MAUI. When debugging with Rider, if the iPhone locks, the debug link drops. Which is annoying.

Now, I know I can set my phone to not auto-lock. However, crucially, it's *my phone* not a work phone and I don't want to have to change it every day.

Is there any way to prevent the device auto-locking when I'm debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn the screen on for debugging.

Under debug, invoke this method:

```
#if DEBUG
public void ToggleScreenLock()
{
    DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn = !DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn;
}
#endif
```

It should be on the main thread.

Comment: Be sure to check related documents so you don't get any unnecessary exceptions